# Выравнивание изображения в сетке

Tags: html, css

Допустим есть сетка из двух рядов по 4 блока в ряду.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В эти блоки вставляются изображения `img` из админки.
Изображения могут быть разные как по ширине, так и по высоте, из-за этого изображения выравниваются только по ширине, и если высота маленькая, то снизу может быть пустое место, и блоки будут смотреться не ровно.
Можно ли сделать стилями, если высота маленькая, то должно выравниваться по высоте, а если ширина маленькая, то должно выравниваться по ширине?

Сейчас для изображений такой стиль:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Обёртка для изображений такая:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
```

Comment: Только стилями - нет. Чтобы все было красиво, можно вставлять изображения через `background-image`, задавать им `background-size: cover` и `background-position: center`, но тогда часть картинки будет обрезаться, не знаю, насколько это для вас критично.
Да, для обёртки в таком случае необходимо задавать фиксированную высоту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
var imgs = $('.col').find('img');
imgs.each(function(){
  var item = $(this).closest('.img-prev');
  item.css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')', 
    'background-position': 'center',
    'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',            
    '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
    'background-size': 'cover', 
  });
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  float:left;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.img-prev {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img-prev">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img-prev">
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plant-growing-picture-id510222832?k=6&m=510222832&s=612x612&w=0&h=Pzjkj2hf9IZiLAiXcgVE1FbCNFVmKzhdcT98dcHSdSk=" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img-prev">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504681869696-d977211a5f4c?auto=format&fit=crop&w=281&q=80&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img-prev">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504006833117-8886a355efbf?auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
.gallery__pict {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.gallery__pict>img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/2000/400/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 gallery__item">
    <div class="gallery__pict"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/1000/sports" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```